# Minimax optimization in PICOS

Tags: python, optimization, minmax, cvxopt, picos-api

I have a generic question on how to solve optimization problems of the Min-Max type, using the PICOS package in Python. I found little information in this context while searching the [PICOS documentation](http://picos.zib.de/tuto_summary.html) and on the web as well.

I can imagine a simple example of the below form.

> Given a matrix M, find x* = argmin_x [ max_y x^T M y ], where x > 0, y > 0, sum(x) = 1 and sum(y) = 1.

I have tried a few methods, starting with the most straightforward idea of having `minimax`, `minmax` keywords in the objective function of PICOS Problem class. It turns out that none of these keywords are valid, see the package [documentation for objective functions](http://picos.zib.de/tuto.html#objective-function). Furthermore, having nested objective functions also turns out to be invalid.

In the last of my naive attempts, I have two functions, Max() and Min() which are both solving a linear optimization problem. The outer function, Min(), should minimize the inner function Max(). So, I have used Max() in the objective function of the outer optimization problem.

```
import numpy as np
import picos as pic
import cvxopt as cvx

def MinMax(mat):
    ## Perform a simple min-max SDP formulated as:
    ## Given a matrix M, find x* = argmin_x [ max_y x^T M y ], where x > 0, y > 0, sum(x) = sum(y) = 1.

    prob = pic.Problem()

    ## Constant parameters
    M = pic.new_param('M', cvx.matrix(mat))
    v1 = pic.new_param('v1', cvx.matrix(np.ones((mat.shape[0], 1))))

    ## Variables
    x = prob.add_variable('x', (mat.shape[0], 1), 'nonnegative')

    ## Setting the objective function
    prob.set_objective('min', Max(x, M))

    ## Constraints
    prob.add_constraint(x > 0)
    prob.add_constraint((v1 | x) == 1)

    ## Print the problem
    print("The optimization problem is formulated as follows.")
    print prob

    ## Solve the problem
    prob.solve(verbose = 0)

    objVal = prob.obj_value()
    solution = np.array(x.value)

    return (objVal, solution)

def Max(xVar, M):
    ## Given a vector l, find y* such that l y* = max_y l y, where y > 0, sum(y) = 1.

    prob = pic.Problem()

    # Variables
    y = prob.add_variable('y', (M.size[1], 1), 'nonnegative')
    v2 = pic.new_param('v1', cvx.matrix(np.ones((M.size[1], 1))))

    # Setting the objective function
    prob.set_objective('max', ((xVar.H * M) * y))

    # Constraints
    prob.add_constraint(y > 0)
    prob.add_constraint((v2 | y) == 1)

    # Solve the problem
    prob.solve(verbose = 0)

    sol = prob.obj_value()

    return sol


def print2Darray(arr):
    # print a 2D array in a readable (matrix like) format on the standard output
    for ridx in range(arr.shape[0]):
        for cidx in range(arr.shape[1]):
            print("%.2e \t" % arr[ridx,cidx]),

        print("")

    print("========")

    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ## Testing the Simple min-max SDP
    mat = np.random.rand(4,4)
    print("## Given a matrix M, find x* = argmin_x [ max_y x^T M y ], where x > 0, y > 0, sum(x) = sum(y) = 1.")
    print("M = ")
    print2Darray(mat)
    (optval, solution) = MinMax(mat)
    print("Optimal value of the function is %.2e and it is attained by x = %s and that of y = %.2e." % (optval, np.array_str(solution)))
```

When I run the above code, it gives me the following error message.

```
10:stackoverflow pavithran$ python minmaxSDP.py 
## Given a matrix M, find x* = argmin_x [ max_y x^T M y ], where x > 0, y > 0, sum(x) = sum(y) = 1.
M = 
1.46e-01    9.23e-01    6.50e-01    7.30e-01    
6.13e-01    6.80e-01    8.35e-01    4.32e-02    
5.19e-01    5.99e-01    1.45e-01    6.91e-01    
6.68e-01    8.46e-01    3.67e-01    3.43e-01    
========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minmaxSDP.py", line 80, in <module>
    (optval, solution) = MinMax(mat)
  File "minmaxSDP.py", line 19, in MinMax
    prob.set_objective('min', Max(x, M))
  File "minmaxSDP.py", line 54, in Max
    prob.solve(verbose = 0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/picos/problem.py", line 4135, in solve
    self.solver_selection()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/picos/problem.py", line 6102, in solver_selection
    raise NotAppropriateSolverError('no solver available for problem of type {0}'.format(tp))
picos.tools.NotAppropriateSolverError: no solver available for problem of type MIQP
10:stackoverflow pavithran$
```

At this point, I am stuck and unable to fix this problem.

Is it just that PICOS does not natively support min-max problem or is my way of encoding the problem, incorrect?

Please note: The reason I am insisting on using PICOS is that ideally, I would like to know the answer to my question in the context of solving a min-max semidefinite program (SDP). But I think the addition of semidefinite constraints is not hard, once I can figure out how to do a simple min-max problem using PICOS.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is that min-max problems are not natively supported in PICOS. However, whenever the inner maximization problem is a convex optimization problem, you can reformulate it as a minimization problem (by taking the Lagrangian dual), and so you get a min-min problem.

Your particular problem is a standard zero-sum game, and can be reformulated as: (assuming `M` is of dimension `n x m`):

```
min_x max_{i=1...m} [M^T x]_i = min_x,t  t  s.t. [M^T x]_i <= t (for i=1...m)
```

In Picos:

```
import picos as pic
import cvxopt as cvx

n=3
m=4
M = cvx.normal(n,m) #generate a random matrix

P = pic.Problem()
x = P.add_variable('x',n,lower=0)
t = P.add_variable('t',1)
P.add_constraint(M.T*x <= t)
P.add_constraint( (1|x) == 1)
P.minimize(t)
print 'the solution is x='
print x
```

If you also need the optimal y, then you can show that it corresponds to the optimal value of the constraint `M'x <= t`:

```
print 'the solution of the inner max-problem is y='
print P.constraints[0].dual
```

Best,
Guillaume.